# Foreign key with Entity Framework Code First and Inherited Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I Have a Company and Employee class, both inherit from a Holder class. 
I'm using Table per Type with EntityFramework 5, to create them in the database

And I have a CheckinTools Class, which uses my Holder class.

```
public class Company : Holder
{       
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
}

public class Employee: Holder
{
    public virtual string Phone { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Holder: IntId
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}    

public class CheckinTool: IntId
{
    public virtual Holder EmployeeCompanyHolder { get; set; }
    public virtual Tool Tool { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CheckinDateTime { get; set; }
}

public class IntId
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm testing the CRUD in my MVC Application everything works fine until I create a CheckinTool, after I have created a CheckinTool, any operation to retrieve an Employee or Company by Id returns the following error: "The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified"

I observed that in my CheckinTool table it has a column called "IdHolder" which has a Foreign Key to Id in the Holder table, while my Employee and Company tables have a Foreign Key to Id, also in the Holder

IMO I solved the problem in a bad way.

I just changed the EmployeeCompany property type in the CheckinTool class from Holder to int
But I feel like something doesn't fit in this solution.

Anyone have any idea on how to solve it without the need to change the EmplotyeeCompany property?

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, because I have never ever used annotations to define mappings between objects and tables. Please consider using Fluent API.

Comment: He's not using an annotation to map.  The annotation tells EF that it's a Key and should be auto generated.

Comment: I'm usgin fluent API only to apply the table per type with Entity Framework, but which annotation I need to use? I'm sorry I didn't understand your comment Maess

Answer (score 0):

CheckInTool should have two columns with fks, one toIntId table (base class) and one to Holder table (sure to Holder property).

I suspect your mapping to tables has a bug. Did you create a table for each class including IntId and Holder?

Comment: I created a table for Holder, but not for IntId(IntId is not mapped by my Context, IntId is included as an Id column in each table I have. 

When these tables are created by the Entity framework they are mapped like this:

Employee = PrimaryKey --> Id; --> ForeingKey --> Id in Holder table --
Company = PrimaryKey --> Id; --> ForeingKey --> Id in Holder table --
CheckinTool = PrimaryKey --> Id; --> ForeingKey --> Id in Holder table and Id in Tools Table --
Holder = PrimaryKey --> Id; No ForeingKey

Comment: @RafaelMiceli in that case, try making IntId an interface instead of a base class.